# How do I install/upgrade to KDE 4.9?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, kubuntu, kde

I want to install and test KDE 4.9 from my Ubuntu 12.04. How can I install KDE 4.9 in Ubuntu? Is there a PPA available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### KDE 4.9 is available in the [Backports](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports) PPA from Kubuntu!

This is the "official" Kubuntu Team PPA.

To install/upgrade, open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```