# Install KDE 4.9 Plasma Netbook on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kde, ubuntu-netbook, plasma-netbook

I'm curious about **KDE 4.9**, and I've seen that there's a desktop specially created for netbooks called **Plasma Netbook** or something like that so I wanted to try it out. Is there any way?

I have installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**, upgraded from 10.04 LTS.
Besides that I've read somewhere that KDE 4.9 brings some problems to the system stability and functionality (*like the Appearance window not opening and some packages uninstalled*), so I wanted your word of wisdom and experience.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/170983 ?

Comment: Actually I read that question, that's where I got some information, but I believe my question is a bit more specific, or at least more focused. Anyway I think that's what make me doubt, but if you find it around.

Answer (score 3):

From http://kde.org/workspaces/plasmanetbook/:

> If you use a small, portable device such as a netbook, then Plasma Netbook is the KDE Workspace for you as it was built specifically for those kinds of devices.

You can install the `kde-plasma-netbook` package to get only the workspace and basic applications. There's also a `kubuntu-netbook` package but it has a dependency on `kubuntu-desktop`, so it installs a lot more (you get Netbook *and* Desktop workspaces.)

By default you'll get KDE 4.8.x. If you want 4.9.x then you'll have to add the [Backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports), as mentioned in [How do I install/upgrade to KDE 4.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170983). As it's also mentioned there, it's a backports repo and it might give you some problems. I have updated to 4.9 (currently 4.9.3) without a single problem, but I use Kubuntu, i.e. no Unity here (although I do have XFCE installed also).

If you really want to try it without having the risk of messing up your system, there's the virtual machine route, like [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).